# Replacing strings on the heap with new ones

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I feel that working with dynamically-typed languages has fried my intuition about this!

Say if I `malloc` space for a string and then update that pointer with another `malloc` (which uses the data from the first), is that a memory leak?

```
char* my_string = (char*)malloc(length + 1);
(void)snprintf(my_string, length, "blah...");

my_string = some_manipulation(my_string);
```

Where we have `char* some_manipulation(const char* str);` assigning memory for its output, which is generated from the provided argument (and may not be the same length).

Is the first `malloc` now lost, but occupying space, until exit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say if I `malloc` space for a string and then update that pointer with another `malloc` (which uses the data from the first), is that a memory leak?

Yes, if you do not store the 1st value of `string`, before overwriting it by the 2nd call to `malloc()`.

**Leaking code**

```
char * p = malloc(42);   
p = malloc(41);

/* here the program leaks 42 bytes. */
```

You can only `free()` the 41 bytes of the 2nd call

```
free(p);
```

as the reference to the 42 bytes block is lost.

**Non-leaking code**

```
char * p = malloc(42);
char * q = p;
p = malloc(41);
```

Here you have no leak, as you still can do:

```
free(p); /* Frees 41 bytes. */
free(q); /* Frees 42 bytes */
```

---

> which uses the data from the first

All of this does not depend at all on **what had been stored** (or not) in the memory allocated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two `malloc` calls and one `free` on the same pointer, you <strike>almost certainly</strike> have a leak (short of the first malloc failing).

Every successful `malloc` should have an associated `free` somewhere at the end of the life of the pointer.

Leak:

```
foo* bar = NULL;
bar = malloc(sizeof(foo) * 10);
if (bar) {
    bar = malloc(sizeof(foo) * 20);
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate memory to bar\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
free(bar);
bar = NULL;
```

No leak:

```
foo* bar = NULL;
bar = malloc(sizeof(foo) * 10);
if (bar) {
    free(bar);
    bar = NULL;
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate memory to bar\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
bar = malloc(sizeof(foo) * 20);
if (bar) {
    free(bar);
    bar = NULL;
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate memory to bar\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. You seem to think about your string here as an *immutable object* which is a nice concept, but doesn't leverage you from freeing the memory occupied.

If you know that the call to your function conceptionally invalidates the input string (so, no caller would ever need it again after calling the function), you could instead do something like this:

```
int some_manipulation(char **str)
{
    char *ret = malloc(...);
    /* handle error, return -1 */
    /* do whatever manipulation */
    free(*str);
    *str = ret;
    return 0;
}
```